# How to balance unbalanced data in PyTorch with WeightedRandomSampler?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a 2-class problem and my data is unbalanced.
class 0 has 232550 samples and class 1 has 13498 samples. 
PyTorch docs and the internet tells me to use the class WeightedRandomSampler for my DataLoader.

I have tried using the WeightedRandomSampler but I keep getting errors.

```
    trainratio = np.bincount(trainset.labels) #trainset.labels is a list of 
    float [0,1,0,0,0,...] 
    classcount = trainratio.tolist()
    train_weights = 1./torch.tensor(classcount, dtype=torch.float)
    train_sampleweights = train_weights[trainset.labels]
    train_sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights=train_sampleweights, 
                                 num_samples=len(train_sampleweights))
    trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, sampler=train_sampler, 
                                       shuffle=False)
```

Some dimensions I printed out:

```
train_weights = tensor([4.3002e-06, 4.3002e-06, 4.3002e-06,  ..., 
4.3002e-06, 4.3002e-06, 4.3002e-06])

train_weights shape=  torch.Size([246048])
```

I can't see why I'm getting this error:

```
UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  self.weights = torch.tensor(weights, dtype=torch.double)
```

I have tried other similar workarounds but so far all attempts produce some error.
How should I implement this to balance my train, validation and test data?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is an internal warning, not an error. According to the guys at PyTorch, I can continue coding and not stress about the warning message.

Comment: Would be helpful if you added a link where you got this information from; in it's current form, it's pretty useless as your post basically only states that it is a warning (which is known already by looking at your question, where your error reads as: `UserWarning`)